# Where is the route table file in SUSE?

Tags: suse, route, table

According to the documentation at

> http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Linux_networking/Suse_networking/suse_etc_sysconfig_network_route.shtml

there should be a table containing the routes at /etc/sysconfig/network/routes.  The script to set up this file is /sbin/init.d/route.  When I run this script I get an error

> No such file or directory exist

.  Am I entering the script wrong or looking for the route table in the wrong place?

Comment: That article is a little unclear. When they say "The file `routes` contains a routing table, which will be set up by the script `/sbin/init.d/route` whenever a networking runlevel (by default runlevels two and three) is reached. ", they mean that `/sbin/init.d/route` will set up a routing table in the kernel based on the contents of the `routes` file. The `routes` file is only present if you create it, either manually or by setting up routes using `yast`.

Comment: So /sbin/init.d/route will only set up a routing table if the route file is already set up.  Do you know how to set up the routes file in SUSE?  When I do a google search it seems to take me to the documentation I have already looked at

Comment: I'd use `yast` - choose Network Settings, then the Routing tab. https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_yast.html#sec_basicnet_yast_change_route . The softpanorama article you cited has a good description of how to set up the `routes` file manually. Are you doing anything more complex than setting a default route?